# ORA-06512:(PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Whenever I'm trying to execute my stored procedure I got error I have doubt in my third parameter FULL_FILE_NAME(K_XVL_10704_20151703_003.000) because I contains dot(.).How can I pass third parameter.Please let me know if I'm doing wrong somewhere.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DE_DUP_PROC2 (Dy_File_Name    IN     VARCHAR2,
                                          SUPPLIER_CD     IN     VARCHAR2,
                                          FULL_FILE_NAME  IN     VARCHAR2)
Declare
                ORGNIZATION_ID VARCHAR2(20);
                v_sql4 VARCHAR2(200);
                DE_DUP_COUNT NUMBER(38);
BEGIN
        SELECT ORG_ID INTO ORGNIZATION_ID FROM ps_org WHERE ORG_SHORT_NM = SUPPLIER_CD;      
        v_sql3 :=

        ' SELECT  count(*) FROM (SELECT stg.*, row_number() over (partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1) AS RN FROM '
        || Dy_File_Name || ' stg ) s JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H ON h.key_clmns_hash = s.key_clmnS_hash
        AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt = s.rx_dspnsd_dt AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD WHERE S.RN > 1 OR s.detl_clmns_hash = h.detl_clmns_hash ' ;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql3 INTO DE_DUP_COUNT;  

        IF   DE_DUP_COUNT > 0
                THEN

                   v_sql4 :=
                            ' declare
                              SRC_ID NUMBER(38) := SRC_FILE_ID_SEQ.nextval;         

                    begin

                         insert into PS_FILE ( SRC_FILE_ID,FILE_NM,FILE_PROC_DT ,ORG_ID) values(SRC_ID,' || FULL_FILE_NAME  ||  ', SYSDATE , ' || ORGNIZATION_ID || ' );
                         commit;

                         FOR i in  (   '
                         || ' SELECT S.TRANS_GUID AS OLD_TRANS_GUID,S.DETL_CLMNS_HASH AS DETL_CLMNS_HASH1 ,S.KEY_CLMNS_HASH AS KEY_CLMNS_HASH1,S.RX_DSPNSD_DT AS R_DSPNSD_DT,
                            S.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD AS SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD1 FROM (SELECT stg.*, row_number() over (partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1) AS RN FROM 
                            '
                         || Dy_File_Name  || ' stg ) s JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H
                            ON h.key_clmns_hash        = s.key_clmnS_hash
                            AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt         = s.rx_dspnsd_dt
                            AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD
                            WHERE S.RN > 1
                            OR s.detl_clmns_hash = h.detl_clmns_hash '  || ')' || '  LOOP   ' || '  ' || '
                            insert into PS_RX_DUPES2(TRANS_GUID,DETL_CLMNS_HASH,KEY_CLMNS_HASH,RX_DSPNSD_DT,SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD,SRC_FILE_ID) 
                            values(i.OLD_TRANS_GUID,i.DETL_CLMNS_HASH1,i.KEY_CLMNS_HASH1,i.R_DSPNSD_DT,i.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD1,SRC_ID);
                            commit; '  || ' END LOOP;'  || ' END;';

                    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql4);

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql4; 

        END IF;

END DE_DUP_PROC2;
```

When I'm executing I got below error:

```
declare

OUTPUT_STATUS number(2);

begin

DE_DUP_PROC2('10655_20150318_04119297','MCL','K_XVL_10704_20151703_003.000');

end;
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 2, column 118:
PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
ORA-06550: line 2, column 16:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06512: at "PS_ADMIN.DE_DUP_PROC2", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about the procedure cannot be compiled - there should be IS/AS instead of DECLARE and you miss declaration of v_sql3 variable.

Secondly, if I assume that FULL_FILE_NAME and ORGANIZATION_ID are values and not column names these must be enclosed with single quotes like

'... values(SRC_ID,''' || FULL_FILE_NAME  ||  ''', SYSDATE , ''' || ORGNIZATION_ID || ''' )'.

Also the length of the v_sql4 is too small.

And most likely more after that.